# get cell from indexPath for expand the row when clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know there is a method called `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` which we can use to get cell at given indexPath.But i want to expand row when the row tapped.using this code-

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {   
        // Deselect cell
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];
        // Toggle 'selected' state
        BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

        // Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
        NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
        int sec = indexPath.section;
        int row = indexPath.row;
        NSString* indexpathStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d", sec, row];

        [selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexpathStr];
        // This is where magic happens...
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];

    }
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        CGFloat height = 0.0;
        if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {
//problem here
            CalEventCell* cell = (CalEventCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
            [self setDescriptionFrame:cell.descriptionLbl];
            height = cell.descriptionLbl.frame.size.height+cell.eventLbl.frame.size.height +20;
        }
        else
            height = 60;
        return height;
    }
```

when a row tapped i call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods on tableview and change row height in heightForAtIndexPath method.The problem is that as you can see i call `cellForAtIndexPath` from `heightForAtIndexPath` and in cellForRow there is `beginUpdates` method call which turn into a call to heightForRow and this loop never ends and program crash with `EXC-BAD-EXCEP`.
So any other method to get cell from indexPath or any other way to do so? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reload Table from didSelectRow and get indexpath from there and Try to set different height for only particular index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Take an array to store the selected indices and then reload that tableview.
- If you tap that cell height will expand and again if you will tap it will decrease its height.

Check out the below code.

```
// Add a mutable array to your class
NSMutableArray *selectedCellArray;

// Initialise it in `viewDidLoad`
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    selectedCellArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}


// Add selected indices in selectedCellArray
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Deselect cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];
    [tableView reloadData];

     if (![selectedCellArray containsObject:indexPath]) 
         [selectedCellArray addObject:indexPath];
     else
         [selectedCellArray removeObject:indexPath];

    [tableView beginUpdates]; // Animate the height change
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

---

```
// Write the UI Updation in HeightForRowAtIndexPath Method
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height = 0.0;

    if (selectedCellArray.count>0) {
        if ([selectedCellArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
            CalEventCell* cell = (CalEventCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [self setDescriptionFrame:cell.descriptionLbl];
            height = cell.descriptionLbl.frame.size.height+cell.eventLbl.frame.size.height+20;

            return height;
        }else{
            height = 60.f;
            return height;
        }
    }
    return height;  
}
```

**Hope This Helps**

Answer (score 2):

You should call below lines of code on your **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method

```
[tableView beginUpdates];    
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:sec]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

When row will be reloaded `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` methods will be called where u can expand cell's height

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` if you are using reusable cells. You need to calculate the height in some other way. The simplest way that would likely work for you would be to keep a prototype cell in your class that you only use for sizing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  

     [your_tableView reloadData];
}
```